# Deploy a NuGet package to folder location during a VSTS release

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I used to use Octopus Deploy and I had steps in my deployment processes where the contents of a NuGet package were deployed to a specific folder on the deployment target. I'm currently using VSTS and I'm looking for a way to deploy the contents of a package (hosted in a feed within VSTS) into a specific destination folder on the deployment target - is this possible with the native functionality of VSTS as it is with Octopus Deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that:

#### Option 1: NuGet restore task

You can specify where to locate the NuGet packages in **Destination directory** option.

#### Option 2: Download Packages task

As Rodrigo mentions, you can use the Download Packages task to download a package.

#### Option 3: Execute nuget command direcly

You can use **Command Line task** or **NuGet custom task** to specify the the package and where to download the packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following task in your release definition.

[image]

As you can see you have to specify the feed in your VSTS, package, version and you also can specify the destination directory.